# While loop inside while loop not helping. Wont exit

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

```
import random#imports random
#Author:
#File name: Lab01.py
#Date: 1/30/2014

#Purpose: To get information from the user and supply other functions with info
#Inputs: None
#Outputs: Bracket display, progress, and instructions
def main():
    wordList=["max","cat","basket","ship","earth","coat","ocean"]#creates set of words        for game to chose from
    theWord=wordList[random.randint(0,len(wordList))]
    theWordList=[]
    for i in range (len(theWord)):
        theWordList.append(theWord[i])#creates list of each character of the word   
    brickDisplay=[]
    for i in range (len(theWordList)):
        brickDisplay.append("-")#Creates the same number of underscores that there are letters in the word
    count=0
    statementCount=0
    wordEnd="go"
    conditionEnd="go"
    userAnswer=raw_input("Type 1 or any button to play, 2 to quit")
    while userAnswer != "2":
        print brickDisplayMaker(brickDisplay)
        letterChoice=raw_input("Enter a letter: ")
        while wordEnd!="stop" or conditionEnd!= "stop" !=theWordList:
                for i in range(len(theWordList)):
                    if theWordList[i]==letterChoice:
                        count=count+1#counts the number of times letterChoice was in the word
                        brickDisplay[i]=letterChoice

                if count<1:
                    statementCount=statementCount+1
                    statementProducer(statementCount)
                conditionEnd=conditionChecker(statementCount)
                wordEnd=wordChecker(theWordList,brickDisplay)
                print brickDisplayMaker(brickDisplay)
                letterChoice=raw_input("Enter a letter: ")
                count=0
        userAnswer=raw_input("Type 1 or any button to play, 2 to quit")
    print "Thanks for playing"
def wordChecker(theWordList,brickDisplay):
    count=0
    for i in range(len(theWordList)):
        if theWordList[i]!=brickDisplay[i]:
            count=count+1
    if count==0:
        return "stop"
    else:
        return "go"
def conditionChecker(statementCount):
    if statementCount==6:
        return "stop"
    else:
        return "go"

#Purpose: Create the brickDisplay with spaces between the underscores
#Inputs: brickDisplay
#Outputs:bricksDisplay with spaces between the underscores
def brickDisplayMaker(brickDisplay):
    officialBrickDisplay=""
    for ndx in brickDisplay:
        officialBrickDisplay=officialBrickDisplay+ndx+" "#creates new list with spaces between underscores
    return officialBrickDisplay 
#Purpose: Produces statement based on the statementCount
#Inputs: statementCount
#Outputs: Statement
def statementProducer(statementCount):

    if statementCount ==1:
        print "draw body part: head"
    elif statementCount==2:
        print "draw body part: body"
    elif statementCount==3:
        print "draw body part: left arm"
    elif statementCount==4:
        print "draw body part: right arm"
    elif statementCount==5:
        print "draw body part: left leg"
    else:
        print "draw body part: right leg. You have lost"


main()
```

it wont exit the second while loop. my teacher said you can't compare lists but i think you can and i dont think thats the problem because it still doesnt work when statementCount=6. I could find ways around this but i'm curious to why this isn't working. Obviously this is suppose to be a hangman game.

here is a working code... The answer I was looking for is that in the while statement it should have been "and" and not "or"

```
import random#imports random

#Author:
#File name: Lab01.py
#Date: 1/30/2014

#Purpose: allow user to play the game of hangman
#inputs:none
#outputs: Text that resembles the game of hangman
def main():
    wordList=["max","cat","basket","ship","earth","coat","ocean"]#creates set of words for game to chose from
    userAnswer=raw_input("Type 1 or any button to play, 2 to quit")
    while userAnswer != "2":
        theWordList=[]
        theWord=wordList[random.randint(0,len(wordList)-1)]
        for i in range (len(theWord)):
            theWordList.append(theWord[i])#creates list of each character of the word   
        brickDisplay=[]
        for i in range (len(theWordList)):
            brickDisplay.append("-")#Creates the same number of underscores that there are letters in the word
        count=0#sets count to 0
        statementCount=0#sets statement count to 0
        print brickDisplayMaker(brickDisplay)
        letterList=[]
        letterChoice=raw_input("Enter a letter: ")
        letterList.append(letterChoice)
        for i in range(len(theWordList)-1):
            if theWordList[i]==letterChoice:#checks for letterchoice in the word
                brickDisplay[i]=theWordList[i]#adds it to the brick display
                count=count+1
        if count==0:#check is statement count is 0
            statementCount=statementCount+1
            statementProducer(statementCount,theWord)
        conditionEnd=conditionChecker(statementCount)#updates conditionEnd
        wordEnd=wordChecker(theWordList,brickDisplay)#updates wordEnd
        count=0#resets count to 0

        print brickDisplayMaker(brickDisplay)
        while wordEnd != "stop" and conditionEnd != "stop":
                letterChoice=raw_input("Enter a letter: ")
                if letterChoice in letterList: #Checks if letter has already been entered by user
                    print "You've already entered that"
                else:
                    letterList.append(letterChoice)
                    for i in range(len(theWordList)):
                        if theWordList[i]==letterChoice:
                            count=count+1#counts the number of times letterChoice was in the word
                            brickDisplay[i]=theWordList[i]
                    print brickDisplayMaker(brickDisplay)
                    if count==0:
                        statementCount=statementCount+1
                        statementProducer(statementCount,theWord)
                    conditionEnd=conditionChecker(statementCount)
                    wordEnd=wordChecker(theWordList,brickDisplay)
                    count=0
                    if wordEnd=="stop":
                        print "You've Won!"


        userAnswer=raw_input("Type 1 or any button to play, 2 to quit")
    print "Thanks for playing"
#Purpose: Check if words are the same
#Inputs: theWordList, brickDisplay
#outputs: "stop" or "go"
def wordChecker(theWordList,brickDisplay):
    count=0
    for i in range(len(theWordList)):
        if theWordList[i]!=brickDisplay[i]:
            count=count+1
    if count==0:
        return "stop"
    else:
        return "go"
#Purpose: Check if statement count equals 6
#inputs: StatementCount
#outputs: "stop" or "go"
def conditionChecker(statementCount):
    if statementCount==6:
        return "stop"
    else:
        return "go"

#Purpose: Create the brickDisplay with spaces between the underscores
#Inputs: brickDisplay
#Outputs:bricksDisplay with spaces between the underscores
def brickDisplayMaker(brickDisplay):
    officialBrickDisplay=""
    for ndx in brickDisplay:
        officialBrickDisplay=officialBrickDisplay+ndx+" "#creates new list with spaces between underscores
    return officialBrickDisplay 
#Purpose: Produces statement based on the statementCount
#Inputs: statementCount
#Outputs: Statement
def statementProducer(statementCount,theWord):
    if statementCount ==1:
        print "Draw body part: head"
    elif statementCount==2:
        print "Draw body part: body"
    elif statementCount==3:
        print "Draw body part: left arm"
    elif statementCount==4:
        print "Draw body part: right arm"
    elif statementCount==5:
        print "Draw body part: left leg"
    else:
        print "Draw body part: right leg. You have lost, the word was "+theWord



main()
```

now an even newer edit working on my coding...

```
import random#imports random

#Author: 
#File name: Lab01.py
#Date: 1/30/2014

#Purpose: allow user to play the game of hangman
#inputs:none
#outputs: Text that resembles the game of hangman
def main():
    wordList=["max","cat","basket","ship","earth","coat","ocean","beach"]#creates set of words for game to chose from

    userAnswer=raw_input("Type 1 or any button to play, 2 to quit: ")
    while userAnswer != "2":
        theWord=wordList[random.randint(0,len(wordList)-1)]
        theWordList=[]
        brickDisplay=[]
        letterList=[]
        count=0#sets count to 0
        statementCount=0#sets statement count to 0

        for i in range (len(theWord)):
            theWordList.append(theWord[i])#creates list of each character of the word   
        brickDisplay=[]
        for i in range (len(theWordList)):
            brickDisplay.append("-")#Creates the same number of underscores that there are letters in the word
        print brickDisplayMaker(brickDisplay)
        letterChoice=raw_input("Enter a letter: ")
        conditionEnd=conditionChecker(statementCount)#updates conditionEnd
        wordEnd=wordChecker(theWordList,brickDisplay)#updates wordEnd
        while wordEnd != "stop" and conditionEnd != "stop":
                while letterChoice in letterList: #Checks if letter has already been entered by user
                    print "You've already entered that"
                    letterChoice=raw_input("Enter a letter: ")

                else:
                    letterList.append(letterChoice)
                    for i in range(len(theWordList)):
                        if theWordList[i]==letterChoice:
                            count=count+1#counts the number of times letterChoice was in the word
                            brickDisplay[i]=theWordList[i]
                    print brickDisplayMaker(brickDisplay)
                    if count==0:
                        statementCount=statementCount+1
                        statementProducer(statementCount,theWord)
                    conditionEnd=conditionChecker(statementCount)
                    wordEnd=wordChecker(theWordList,brickDisplay)
                    count=0
                    if wordEnd=="stop":
                        print "You've Won!"
                    elif conditionEnd=="stop":
                        print "You have lost, the word was "+theWord #lets user know what the word was
                    else:    
                        letterChoice=raw_input("Enter a letter: ")


        userAnswer=raw_input("Type 1 or any button to play, 2 to quit: ")
    print "Thanks for playing" #exists main
#Purpose: Check if words are the same
#Inputs: theWordList, brickDisplay
#outputs: "stop" or "go"
def wordChecker(theWordList,brickDisplay):
    count=0
    for i in range(len(theWordList)):
        if theWordList[i]!=brickDisplay[i]:
            count=count+1
    if count==0:
        return "stop"
    else:
        return "go"
#Purpose: Check if statement count equals 6
#inputs: StatementCount
#outputs: "stop" or "go"
def conditionChecker(statementCount):
    if statementCount==6:
        return "stop"
    else:
        return "go"

#Purpose: Create the brickDisplay with spaces between the underscores
#Inputs: brickDisplay
#Outputs:bricksDisplay with spaces between the underscores
def brickDisplayMaker(brickDisplay):
    officialBrickDisplay=""
    for ndx in brickDisplay:
        officialBrickDisplay=officialBrickDisplay+ndx+" "#creates new list with spaces between underscores
    return officialBrickDisplay 
#Purpose: Produces statement based on the statementCount
#Inputs: statementCount
#Outputs: Statement
def statementProducer(statementCount,theWord):
    if statementCount ==1:
        print "Draw body part: head"
    elif statementCount==2:
        print "Draw body part: body"
    elif statementCount==3:
        print "Draw body part: left arm"
    elif statementCount==4:
        print "Draw body part: right arm"
    elif statementCount==5:
        print "Draw body part: left leg"
    else:
        print "Draw body part: right leg"



main()
```

Comment: "my teacher said you can't compare lists". You definitely can. `[1,2] < [1,3]`

Comment: This program is really overcomplicated. I'm working on it though.

Comment: last code is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to totally edit your program as there a few things that could have gone wrong and I would rather show you an easier way to do things then try to keep patching up your old code. This is going to be a long answer btw.

Here is the complete working program. I wrote in Python 3.3 because that's what I have on my machine but I don't think anything should be different for Python 2.x except the `print`s and the `input`s. If you have any questions just let me know.

This line:

```
while wordEnd!="stop" or conditionEnd!= "stop" !=theWordList:
```

has a few problems. You are missing an `or` and half of the last statement. You would need to change this to:

```
while wordEnd != "stop" or conditionEnd != "stop" or something_else != theWordList:
```

Looking at that I would rethink whether or not you need that while loop.

```
import random
# Author:
# File name: Lab01.py
# Date: 1/30/2014


# Purpose: To get information from the user and supply other functions with info
# Inputs: None
# Outputs: Bracket display, progress, and instructions
def main():
    word_list = ["max", "cat", "basket", "ship", "earth", "coat", "ocean"]  # creates set of words for game to chose from
    word = random.choice(word_list)  # chooses a random word form the list
    brick_display = ['_'] * len(word)  # Creates the same number of underscores that there are letters in the word
    guesses = []  # tracks the letters the user has used
    count = 0
    wrong = 0
    while True:
        print(' '.join(brick_display))
        print(guesses)
        print(word)
        try:
            guess = input('Please enter a letter >> ')
            if guess not in guesses:
                index = check_guess(guess, word)
                if index >= 0:
                    brick_display[index] = guess
                else:
                    wrong += 1
                    statement_producer(wrong)
            else:
                print('You already guessed that letter')

            if guess == 'exit':
                break
            count += 1
            guesses.append(guess)
            if count >= len(word):
                if check_for_win(word, brick_display):
                    print('You win!!')
                    again = int(input('Play again? 1 for YES, 2 for NO'))
                    word = random.choice(word_list)
                    brick_display = ['_'] * len(word) 
                    guesses = []
                    count = 0
                    wrong = 0
                    if again == 1:
                        pass
                    else:
                        break
                elif wrong == 6:
                    print('You lose!!')
                    again = int(input('Play again? 1 for YES, 2 for NO'))
                    if again == 1:
                        pass
                    else:
                        break

        except ValueError:
            print('Please enter a letter')

print("Thanks for playing")


#Purpose: Checks if the guess is in the word
#Inputs: guess, word
#Outputs: If true: index of correct guess else: -1 
def check_guess(guess, word):
    for i in range(len(word)):
        if guess == word[i]:
            return i
    return -1


#Purpose: Checks if the user has correctly guessed the word
#Inputs: word, guess
#Outputs:True or False
def check_for_win(word, guess):
    if ''.join(guess) == word:
        return True
    return False


#Purpose: Produces statement based on the number of wrong guesses
#Inputs: wrong
#Outputs: Statement
def statement_producer(wrong):
    if wrong == 1:
        print("draw body part: head")
    elif wrong == 2:
        print("draw body part: body")
    elif wrong == 3:
        print("draw body part: left arm")
    elif wrong == 4:
        print("draw body part: right arm")
    elif wrong == 5:
        print("draw body part: left leg")
    else:
        print("draw body part: right leg. You have lost")


main()
```

Comment: My question was why is it not exiting the second while loop. So I appreciate all of this but I still don't have the answer to my question. I obviously cannot turn in something like this because my teacher would know someone just did it for me...

Comment: Okay so i changed the while loop with the original code and it still does not work it continues to print the last statement and allows you to continue guessing... why?

Comment: CAn you update your question with the code you have now?

Comment: I updated my code I got it to work and also I restated what I was looking for.

Comment: appreciate the input from all looking at everything

Comment: Working fine but if you want to improve it somethings to read up on would be `' '.join()`, list comprehensions and examining your logic. I think you have a few unnecessary variable/comparisons. You can post your code on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to ask for tips on how to improve it.

Comment: thanks thats awesome I didn't know about that website

Answer (score 0):

Replace the line 
 **while userAnswer != 2:**

with

**while userAnswer != "2":**

Comment: To expand: Python is dynamically typed but unlike many other dynamically typed languages (e.g. Javascript and PHP), Python is also *strongly* typed, which means it doesn't do implicit conversions like `"2"` to `2`.